# Pass parameters to AWS Lamda function in Python without API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am currently working on my lambda function (Python) which is triggered using cron expression in CloudWatch Events.

I want to pass some data to the function (ideally in the form of a dictionary) and those values can then be used inside the `lambda_handler` to do calculations based on the custom input parameters.

I did some research and there are methods using the API gateway but I do not have the liberty to use the API gateway.

Is there a way I can pass custom input parameters to my function?
I am new to `AWS` `Lambda` so this question might seem silly to veterans.
Thanks in advance

Edit 1:
After trying out the solution provided in the first answer I faced come other issues.

Input Config:
[image]

Here's the snippet from the lambda function where im trying to push input data into Postgres database:

```
s={'upload_date': today,'data':'Test Data','Remark':event["data"]}
log_success = pd.DataFrame(data = [s])
log_success.to_sql(log_table, con, schema = "some_existing_schema", if_exists = "append",index = False, method = "multi")
```

ERROR:

> [ERROR] KeyError: 'data'
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/var/task/test.py", line 38, in lambda_handler
>       s={'upload_date': today,''data':'Test Data','Remark':event["data"]}

Comment: Can you provide some code example of what you already did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure your lambda as target in your CW Event rule, you can `Configure inputs` which will be passed to your function.

For example, you can pass a **constant string or json**:

[image]

Using [Input transformer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-Input-Transformer-Tutorial.html) you can   modify regular CW event data that is normally passed to your function, and add extra information to it.

But you have to remember that these are **fixed inputs**. For every invocation of your function by `cron` from CW Events rule, the input parameters will be same.

If you want to trigger your lambda function yourself and pass custom arguments each time, then you either have to use aws api (e.g. `aws lambda invoke` AWS CLI) or do it through a API gateway. The first method will require **AWS credentials** to invoke the function, while the second one can be made public and work without AWS credentials.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. Elaborate more on the first method you suggested (aws lambda invoke AWS-CLI) or share some resources? I feel there is not enough about this in the AWS documentation

Comment: @umangMistryBO The direct invokation of the function is documented [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html). For that to work you would have to install [aws cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and setup your [aws credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) to be used by the cli.

Comment: Is there a way to schedule the invoking? Cause upon observing the documentation you shared there is no schedule-expression mentioned.

Comment: Hi I tried out the method of fixed input with the scheduled Rule in AWS CW (Image attached above). I tried to access it in the function and Im getting an error. Could you point out where I'm missing out? Thanks

Comment: I have added a new question for the new error. Would love to get some help. Thanks